# Microsoft SQL Server 2017 / 2019 on Docker Container Slow Performance

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have a performance problems deploying SQL Server on Docker. I write as docker-compose like this :

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mssql:
    restart: always
    container_name: mssql
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    user: root
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=PASSWORD-SA
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
    volumes:
      - /store/backup:/var/opt/mssql/backup:rw
      - /store/data:/var/opt/mssql/data:rw
      - /store/log:/var/opt/mssql/log:rw
      - /store/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets:rw
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-file: "1"
        max-size: "1m"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: 0.75
          memory: 80G
```

Everything work well, but in running production query very slow.
Compare to select a table with same data row - result very difference:

- DOCKER : need 1 minutes 48 seconds
- GCP SQL : 27 Seconds - In GCP just use 8 Core an 12Gb memory.

Any suggestion about tuning SQL Server on Docker?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check how much memory has actually been allocated to SQL Server? Your container has 80GB but I think the default it will allocate to SQL Server is a lot lower. Also why have you given a container with 80GB of memory 3/4ths of a CPU?

Comment: Well `cpus: 0.75` isn't 75% of all of the host's available CPU cores, it's 75% of just a single core. REF: [Docker Compose - resources](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#resources)

Comment: Thanks alot mr @AlwaysLearning and Aaron Bertrand
you save my live

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for comments from Mr @AlwaysLearning and @AaronBertrand.
I change docker-compose on resources

```
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: 40
          memory: 100G
```

After that i change max memory on TSQL with :

```sql
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory', 100000;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

And everthing fast right now.